# MVC javascript https

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, https

So I use https on one page on website, and javascript doesn't work there, browser is blocking it because it is not secured.

How do you render javascript as https through MVC render strategy?

Comment: Is the javascript file hosted on the same domain?  Can you just make the source URL use HTTPS as well?

Comment: JavaScript in the same application will be referenced on the page relatively, which means it will automatically pick up the HTTPS if the site itself is using HTTPS. For third-party scripts (which includes scripts owned by you but on a different domain), you're responsible for the on-page reference, anyways, so just make it HTTPS if that's what you want. Of course, check with the provider as the secure version will often be served under an HTTPS specific domain.